# use of use `getfilterinstance` in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

i have a doubt, i use `gridapi.getfilterinstance` in the angular app it works fine.
but the main problem is that i create a custom search box and i have two columns in grid table `firstname` and `lastname`

i want to search in both of them.
what i create is

```js
  onSearch() {
    const row = this.reportTable.gridApi.getFilterInstance('contact.firstName');
    let filter = this.form.value['text'];
    let condition = {
      type: 'startsWith',
      filter
    };
    row.setModel(condition);
    this.reportTable.gridApi.onFilterChanged();
  }
```

```html
<button class="primary-btn mr-2" (click)="onSearch()">
 Search
</button>
```

i need another condition with this firstname instance i,e. `contact.lastName` which is trigger with the same search button and search field.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using an [external filter](https://ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/filter-external/#top). This enables you to search based on whatever condition you want. In your case this would be against firstName and lastName. Main steps are:

1. Provide a function that returns true when you want to use your external filter to `isExternalFilterPresent`
2. Implement `doesExternalFilterPass` with your custom logic.

I have created a plunkr based of the documentation example that shows filtering based off both the athlete name or country.

https://plnkr.co/edit/9DkvMyH234Xr8CJo